# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr in revtex4-2

Tags: tables

I'm using the revtex4-2 for writing an article in Overleaf. I have the problem with the tables. I get an error saying extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. I think that the number of columns is correct.

How do I correct this? Here is mine code.

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{romannum}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

\caption{\label{table2} Spatial parts.%
}

\begin{ruledtabular}

\begin{tabular}{cccc
}

\textrm{IR}&

\textrm{fun}&
\textrm{\Romannum{1} type\footnote{Nodes due to the cancellation of function of one row of IR}}&
\textrm{\Romannum{2} type\footnote{Nodes due to the cancellation of functions of two rows of IR}}& 
\hline
$\Psi _{1}\left( E_{g}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}-\psi _{C_{2z}}+\psi _{\sigma
_{x}}-\psi _{\sigma _{y}}$ & $(010),(001)$ & $(\bar{1}10)$ \\ 
$\Psi _{2}\left( E_{g}\right) $ & $\psi _{C_{4z}}-\psi _{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi
_{\sigma _{a}}-\psi _{\sigma _{b}}$ & $(100),(001)$ & - \\ 
$\Psi _{1}\left( E_{g}^{A_{2g}}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}-\psi _{C_{2z}}-\psi
_{\sigma _{x}}+\psi _{\sigma _{y}}$ & $(001)$ & $(110)$ \\ 
$\Psi _{2}\left( E_{g}^{A_{2g}}\right) $ & $+\psi _{\sigma _{b}}-\psi
_{\sigma _{a}}-\psi _{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi _{C_{4z}}$ & $(001)$ & - \\ 
$\Psi _{1}\left( \tilde{E}_{g}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}+i\psi _{C_{4z}}-\psi
_{C_{2z}}-i\psi _{C_{4z}^{3}}$ & $(001)$ & $(100)$ \\ 
$\Psi _{2}\left( \tilde{E}_{g}\right) $ & $\psi _{\sigma _{y}}-i\psi
_{\sigma _{b}}-\psi _{\sigma _{x}}+i\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & $(001)$ & $%
(110),(-110)\footnote{Deeps due to partial cancellation of functions of two rows of IR}$ \\ 
$\Psi _{1}\left( \tilde{E}_{g}^{A_{2g}}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}+i\psi
_{C_{4z}}-\psi _{C_{2z}}-i\psi _{C_{4z}^{3}}$ & $(001)$ & $(010)$ \\ 
$\Psi _{2}\left( \tilde{E}_{g}^{A_{2g}}\right) $ & $-\psi _{\sigma
_{y}}+i\psi _{\sigma _{b}}+\psi _{\sigma _{x}}-i\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & $%
(001) $ & $(110),(-110)$\footnotemark[3] \\ 
$\Psi (A_{1g})$ & $\psi _{E}+\psi _{C_{2z}}+\psi _{C_{4z}}+\psi
_{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi _{\sigma _{x}}+\psi _{\sigma _{y}}+\psi _{\sigma
_{b}}+\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & - & - \\ 
$\Psi \left( A_{2g}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}+\psi _{C_{2z}}+\psi _{C_{4z}}+\psi
_{C_{4z}^{3}}-\psi _{\sigma _{x}}-\psi _{\sigma _{y}}-\psi _{\sigma
_{b}}-\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & $\ \left( 100\right) $, $\left( 010\right) $, $%
\left( 110\right) ,$ $(-110)$   & -\\ 
$\Psi \left( B_{1g}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}+\psi _{C_{2z}}-\psi _{C_{4z}}-\psi
_{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi _{\sigma _{x}}+\psi _{\sigma _{y}}-\psi _{\sigma
_{b}}-\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & $\left( 110\right) ,$ $(-110)$   & -\\ 
$\Psi \left( B_{2g}\right) $ & $\psi _{E}+\psi _{C_{2z}}-\psi _{C_{4z}}-\psi
_{C_{4z}^{3}}-\psi _{\sigma _{x}}-\psi _{\sigma _{y}}+\psi _{\sigma
_{b}}+\psi _{\sigma _{a}}$ & $\left( 100\right) $, $\left( 010\right) $  & - \\

\end{tabular}

\end{ruledtabular}

\end{table*}
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Zarko. Thank you for your answer! It doesn't work possibly I'm inattentive. If you don't mind may you write correct code please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
\textrm{\Romannum{2} type\footnote{Nodes due ... two rows of IR}}&
```

to

```
\textrm{\Romannum{2} type\footnote{Nodes due ... two rows of IR}}\\
```

i.e., replace the terminal `&` character with `\\`.

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic, just for fun:

I would design your table as follows:

[image]

- For table is used `talltblr` of `tabularray` package.
- For table notes are used `TblrNote{<label>}` (text of notes are listed in table preamble, see MWE below)
- Since `{revtex4-2}` overwrite default positioning of notes, for it is used trick to extend their length (by inserting of `\hfill~` at end of notes text)

```
\documentclass[reprint,
               amssymb,
               aps,
               ]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{romannum}
% new
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
%
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Spatial parts.},
  label = {table2},
%
note{a} = {Nodes due to the cancellation of function of one row of IR\hfill~}, % <---
note{b} = {Nodes due to the cancellation of functions of two rows of IR\hfill~},
note{c} = {Deeps due to partial cancellation of functions of two rows of IR\hfill~},
note{d} = {unknown text\hfill~},
                 ]{colspec = {@{} Q[l, mode=math] 
                              X[l, mode=math] 
                         *{2}{Q[l, mode=math]}
                              @{}},
                   row{1}  = {mode=text}
                   }
    \toprule
IR  &   fun
        &   \Romannum{1} type \TblrNote{a}                      
            &   \Romannum{2} type \TblrNote{b}  \\     
    \midrule
\Psi_{1} (E_{g})
    &   \psi_{E}-\psi_{C_{2z}}+\psi_{\sigma_{x}}-\psi_{\sigma_{y}}
        &   (010),\ (001) 
            &   (\bar{1}10)                     \\
\Psi_{2}(E_{g})
    &   \psi_{C_{4z}}-\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi_{\sigma_{a}}-\psi_{\sigma_{b}} 
        &   (100),(001)                         \\
\Psi_{1}(E_{g}^{A_{2g}})
    &   \psi_{E}-\psi_{C_{2z}}-\psi_{\sigma_{x}}+\psi_{\sigma_{y}}
        &   (001) 
            &   (110)                           \\
\Psi_{2}(E_{g}^{A_{2g}})
    & +\psi_{\sigma_{b}}-\psi_{\sigma_{a}}-\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}}+\psi_{C_{4z}}
        &   (001) 
            &   \textendash                     \\
\Psi_{1}(\tilde{E}_{g})
    & \psi_{E}+i\psi_{C_{4z}}-\psi_{C_{2z}}-i\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}}
        &   (001)
            &   (100)                           \\
\Psi_{2}(\tilde{E}_{g})
    &   \psi_{\sigma_{y}}-i\psi_{\sigma_{b}}-\psi_{\sigma_{x}}+i\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   (001)
            &   (110),\; (-110) \TblrNote{c}    \\
\Psi_{1}(\tilde{E}_{g}^{A_{2g}})
    &   \psi_{E}+i\psi_{C_{4z}}-\psi_{C_{2z}}-i\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}}
        &   (001)
            &   (010)                           \\
\Psi_{2}(\tilde{E}_{g}^{A_{2g}})
    & -\psi_{\sigma_{y}}+i\psi_{\sigma_{b}}+\psi_{\sigma_{x}}-i\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   (001)
            &   (110),\; (-110) \TblrNote{d}    \\
\Psi (A_{1g})
    &   \psi_{E}+\psi_{C_{2z}}+\psi_{C_{4z}}+\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}} +
        \psi_{\sigma_{x}}+\psi_{\sigma_{y}} +
        \psi_{\sigma_{b}}+\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   \textendash
            &   \textendash                     \\
\Psi(A_{2g})  
    &   \psi_{E}+\psi_{C_{2z}}+\psi_{C_{4z}} +
        \psi_{C_{4z}^{3}}-\psi_{\sigma_{x}}-\psi_{\sigma_{y}} -
        \psi_{\sigma_{b}}-\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   (100),\; (010),\; (110),\; (-110)
            &   \textendash                     \\
\Psi (B_{1g})
    &   \psi_{E}+\psi_{C_{2z}}-\psi_{C_{4z}}-\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}} +
        \psi_{\sigma_{x}}+\psi_{\sigma_{y}} -
        \psi_{\sigma_{b}}-\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   (110), (-110)
            &   \textendash                     \\
\Psi (B_{2g})
    &   \psi_{E}+\psi_{C_{2z}} - \psi_{C_{4z}}-\psi_{C_{4z}^{3}} -
        \psi_{\sigma_{x}}-\psi_{\sigma_{y}} +
        \psi_{\sigma_{b}}+\psi_{\sigma_{a}}
        &   (100) , (010)
            &   \textendash                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the pointkess `\left` and `\right` sizing directives. You may further want to replace all instances of `--` with `\text{--}` or, better yet, `\textendash`.

Comment: @Zarko. Thank you for your amazing answer. I have one question yet if you don't mind. How to make the caption of the table in the left corner instead of the center? Thank you!

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Use of `\textendash` is far better.  Corrected now.

Comment: @UserIn, default features of `revtex4.2`  is to write caption with uppercase characters and centered caption. Do you like to change this?

Comment: @Zarko. Yes. Just change centered caption(transfer it  to the left corner) without changing uppercase characters.

Comment: I don't know how to do this for any float (table), however if you use `talltblr` you can do the following: (i) in preamble  write `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            skip=0pt]{caption}
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%
{\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }` and add to table preamble:`\begin{talltblr}[
  theme = captionof,
....]{....}`.

Comment: @Zarko. Thank you for your help and for your time!

Comment: @UserIn, you are welcome. BTW, when you will have sufficient reputation (more than 1 :-)5 points) you can upvote my answer :-).